# Why the execution is failing by saying path not found?

Tags: windows, vbscript

Why its failing to execute the `API_SDK.exe` with command line argument that I am passing via `cmd.vbs`?

[image]

```
> cmd.vbs "execute#abcd 1234/"
```

**cmd.vbs:**

```
result = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
splits = Split(result, "#")
split_result = splits(1)
main_command = Replace(split_result, "/", "")

Set LoginScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strCurDir = LoginScript.CurrentDirectory
run_command = strCurDir & "\API_SDK.exe " & main_command

box = MsgBox(main_command, vbYesNo + vbInformation, "")
WScript.Echo run_command

' FAILING TO EXECUTE
LoginScript.Run run_command, 0, False
```

**EDIT:**

```
' 1 - Spoon feed
Function Quotes(Byval strValue)
    Quotes = Chr (34) & strValue & Chr(34)
end Function 

' 2 - Command line argument / parser
result = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
splits = split(result, "://")
split_result=splits(1)
main_command = Replace(split_result, "/", "")

' 3 - Prepare pathing 
Set LoginScript    = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'strCurDir = LoginScript.CurrentDirectory
run_command = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ABCD XYZ 1234\api_sdk.exe"


' 4 - Seeing is believing 
strCommand = Quotes(run_command) & " " & main_command
box=Msgbox(strCommand,vbYesNo+vbInformation, "")
WScript.Echo box

' 5 - Run that mother
LoginScript.Run strCommand, 0, False
```

Comment: It is a very basic error.  You'll have to tell us what the value of strCurDir is and where the .exe file is actually stored.

Comment: Can you try it this way: `LoginScript.Run """"&run_command&"""", 0, False`

Comment: Right now it is probably trying to execute C:\Program and passing "files (x86) ...etc" as the arguments.  You'll need to put double quotes around the string to avoid trouble with the spaces in the path.

Comment: You need to put the executable path in double quotes, not the entire commandline.